# using iterator in cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I am trying to learn cython and I modified the example found [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/tutorials-numpy).

```
#pyx file

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

np.import_array()

def test1(a):
    out = np.empty(a.shape, np.double)

    cdef np.flatiter ita = np.PyArray_IterNew(a)
    cdef np.flatiter ito = np.PyArray_IterNew(out)

    cdef double value

    cdef double i
    i = 0.0

    while np.PyArray_ITER_NOTDONE(ita):

        value = (<double*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita))[0]

        print(ita)  # for debugging
        print(value,i)  # for debugging

        value = value + i

        (<double*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ito))[0] = value

        i += 1.0

        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(ita)
        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(ito)

    return out
```

So I expect the function to add each element of the input array by `i`, where the value of `i` increases by one each time the iterator passes to the next element. When I run the function with `a=np.arange(10)`, the print statement shows something like:

```
(2.121995791e-314, 0.0)
(<numpy.flatiter object at 0x0000024A2CE27B20>)

(4.2439915824e-314, 1.0)
(<numpy.flatiter object at 0x0000024A2CE27B20>)

(6.365987374e-314, 2.0)
(<numpy.flatiter object at 0x0000024A2CE27B20>)

(8.4879831653e-314, 3.0)
(<numpy.flatiter object at 0x0000024A2CE27B20>)
# rest not shown here
```

which isn't what I expect as it seems that the iterator is still pointing to the same element of the array, and the value returned by `value` is essentially zero, but not the values of `a` (number 0-9). But the iterator does seem to stop at the end as the function terminates successfully and the returned array has the same shape as `a`.

So my question is:

1. What does the line `value = (<double*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita))[0]` actually mean? `<double*>` declares the pointer type? `np.PyArray_ITER_DATA` is just what the API says. Then what about `[0]`?
2. What did I get wrong and how to modify the code? If `a=np.arange(2,8)`, then `test1(a)` should give `array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12])`.

Comment: I think you're passing in arrays with an integer dtype then trying to read then as double

Comment: @DavidW you are right. When I declared `a` explicitly to be of type `float64`, then it works as expected. What why does this matter? And my 1st question remains. I'm still not sure what that line actually does and I want to know why `print(ita)` gives the same address even if `ita` is indeed accessing different element of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that `arange` gives you an `int` array by default, which you're then interpreting as if it was a `double` array (small integers misinterpreted as doubles are often around 1e-300 ish, so this is usually a good clue). Ideally you should make sure you check the `dtype` in the function.

To answer your further questions:

`print(ita)` is printing the address of the iterator object, not the data it's currently accessing. Therefore it always shows the same address.

`np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)` gets a pointer to the address of the current bit of data. Since it's designed as a generic interface for any numpy array we don't know the type so it's a `void*`. `<double*>` is you telling Cython that this pointer actually points to a `double`. `[0]` looks up the value stored at that pointer